# Openswan shows no installation candidate after running apt-get update

Tags: server, openswan

I have ubuntu server 16.04 installed, with a working internet connection but running `apt-get install openswan` still fails, giving `E: Package 'openswan' has no installation candidate`. Does anyone know what could be going on?

Comment: It simply means what the error message says: the package `openswan` does not exist for Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 15):

The `openswan` package is not available for Ubuntu 16.04, but the (very similar) `strongswan` package is available.

Try running

```
sudo apt-get install strongswan
```

to install StrongSwan. There might be some minor differenced between OpenSwan and StrongSwan in configuration files, etc... but they should be minor.

You can view  details about the `strongswan` package for Ubuntu 16.04 here: http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/strongswan and details about StrongSwan in general at http://strongswan.org

Answer (score 0):

Run:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then search for your package in cache file

```
sudo apt-cache search term
```

Instead of "term" put a part of or exact package's name,
if it finds your Package run:

```
sudo apt-get install <packagename>
```

If you don't answer with this method You should add a new repository that has this Package or download  openswan.deb and then install it from downloaded path

Comment: it returns
`ike - Shrew Soft VPN client - Daemon and libraries
kvpnc - frontend to VPN clients`
what should it show